# How to imshow a picture in GUI axis in matlab with pushbutton

Tags: matlab

I will How  to  imshow a picture in  GUI axis in matlab with pushbutton , i'm create this code :

```
AxesPourAfficherImage = findobj('Tag', 'Image');
function OpenFile_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)


        [FileName,PathName] = uigetfile({'*.png';'*.tif';'JPG.tif'},'Choisir une photo ')
        Image = imread(strcat(PathName,FileName));
        axes(hendleAxesPourAfficherImage)
        imshow(Image)
        save('LesVariables')
```

But this code not work , because When i press to button , seems to me an other figure . how resolved the problem ?

Comment: What is `hendleAxesPourAfficherImage` ? You didn't define it. You have to define your GUI axes as `axes`. And if you have another open figure, you should define the current axes inside `findobj`, in its first input.

Comment: @Adiel yes  , define the current axes inside findobj, in its first input ! 
The problem remains the same

Comment: You defined it outside the function. And you use for it in two different names.  Actually I don't understand why you need here `findobj` at all... what wrong with just `axes(handles.name_of_your_GUI_axes_handle)`

Comment: Ok, step by step. You know what is the name of the axes' handle in the GUI?

Comment: How get the the axes' handle in the GUI? 
findobj('Tag','Name of objet') ??

Comment: No. The GUI was done by guide or programmatically?